Testing a SSE endpoint in Go
I'm trying to write a test in Go to verify the behavior of a Server-Sent Events (SSE) endpoint implemented using the Fiber framework. My goal is to ensure that the client can successfully disconnect from the server, even though the server is designed to keep the connection open indefinitely.
func Test_WatcherStream_Returns200(t *testing.T) {
    entityID := uuid.New().String()

    req := httptest.NewRequest("GET", fmt.Sprintf("/watchers/%s", entityID), nil)
    resp, err := app.Test(req, -1)
    
    assert.NoError(t, err)
    assert.Equal(t, http.StatusOK, resp.StatusCode)

    err = resp.Body.Close()
    assert.NoError(t, err)
}

I've tried a few things but I'm a bit stuck at this point.
Multiple methods including using request with context and attempting to cancel gracefully from there.

What happens when you do this?  Nothing can prevent a client from closing the socket whenever they want.

please read the tag before tagging. [tag:sse] is about the Intel SSE extension and has nothing to do with Server-Sent Events
